# Is it legitimate to include Java VM Specification document in my derived work?

Tags: licensing, java, permissive

I'm planning to make a bytecode viewer for Java 17 classfiles,
and distribute my work under some permissive license.
For convenience of implemenation, I'd like to include
[JVMS Chapter 4. The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html)
into my repository.
So I glanced [Appendix A. Limited License Grant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/spec-license.html)
but it was beyond my scope of understanding.

Please teach me whether and how it is compliant
to include the portion of JVMS in my derived work
and distribute my work under permissive license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the license you linked in your question, you cannot include the specification in your offering.

> 1. License for Evaluation Purposes. Specification Lead hereby grants you a fully-paid, non-exclusive, non-transferable, worldwide, limited
>    license (**without the right to sublicense**), under Specification Lead's
>    applicable intellectual property rights to view, download, use and
>    reproduce the Specification **only for the purpose of internal**
>    **evaluation**. ...

(Emphasis added)

It would be OK for you to link to the original website with Oracle's information, but you cannot take it and distribute it yourself.